# Agregar 2FK en una sola tabla

Tags: mysql

**Tengo estas tablas:**

```
mysql> describe clientes;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_cliente     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nombre_cliente | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| calle_cliente  | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ciudad_cliente | varchar(12) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> describe saldo;
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| numero_cuenta | varchar(5) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| saldo         | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

> Pero quiero hacer una tabla con las llaves primarias de cada tabla,
>   ¿se puede? Si es así, ¿cómo?

Comment: Si se puede, y tiene nombre. Es una relación de muchos a muchos. En este enlace tienes más información: http://www.ite.educacion.es/formacion/materiales/93/cd/m2_3/muchos_a_muchos.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede y se llama una relación de muchos a muchos, se hace del siguiente modo:

```
CREATE TABLE cliente_saldo(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   cliente_id INT NOT NULL,
   saldo_id INT NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT fk_cliente_saldo_clientes FOREIGN KEY(cliente_id) REFERENCES clientes(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT fk_cliente_saldo_saldos FOREIGN KEY(saldo_id) REFERENCES saldos(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

**EXPLICACIÓN.**

> 1. cliente_id = Es el campo que actuará como llave foránea y dado que lo vamos a vincular con un id de tipo INT, por eso yo también lo
>      declaré como INT; esta misma situación explica la creación de saldo_id
> 2. cliente_saldo_clientes y cliente_saldo_saldos son los alias necesarios que deben llevar cada una de las llaves foráneas para
>      poderlas identificar; checa como cada una inicia por el nombre de la
>      tabla nueva y luego por el nombre de cada tabla a la que hago
>      referencia
> 3. Cuando utilizo ONDELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, estoy manejando la integridad referencial para saber que ocurre cuando elimino un nodo
>      padre y que va a pasar con el nodo hijo asociado a ese nodo padre.
>
> Aquí mas info de la integridad referencial
>
> CASCADE: Borra los registros de la tabla B, cuando se borra el
>   registro de la tabla A; de la cual dependen si la sentencia es DELETE
>   y modifica los registros de la tabla b cuando el registro de la tabla
>   A es modificado en la sentencia UPDATE

Comment: Pero yo necesito hacer la tabla con la llave primaria "id_cliente" y la llave primaria "numero_cuenta_" no afecta??

Comment: no puedes usar numero_cuenta como llave primaria por que es varchar y las llaves primarias deben ser de tipo int por lo tanto por el tipo de dato te va a marcar error @AldoMunoZz

Comment: Ok muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

estimado en una tabla siempre debe existir una llave primaria , por lo tanto si quieres tener la llave primaria de cada tabla en una tabla tienes que pasarlo como llave foranea.

Comment: HABÍA INTENTADO ALGO ASÍ 

create table depositante
    -> (constraint id_cliente1 foreign key (id_cliente) references clientes(id_cliente), Fecha DATE );

PERO NO PUEDO AGREGAR LA FK DE LA OTRA TABLA